# How to prevent React component from re-rendering when I am changing routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have React components: allUsersList and userDetail. In the first one I am fetching all of the users and displaying them and by clicking each of them I am changing route and going to the second component but when I click arrow to go back on browser first component starts fetching data and re-rendering again. Could you please tell me how an I prevent it from doing extra re-render?

This is the AllUsers component:

```
import React, {useEffect, useMemo} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {setAllUsers, setLoading, setPage} from '../redux/actions/actions';
import User from './User';
import '../styles/AllUsersList.css';

const AllUsersList = () => {
    const allUsers = useSelector(state => state.setAllUsersReducer);
    const page = useSelector(state => state.setPageReducer);
    const loading = useSelector(state => state.setLoadingReducer);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  

    const fetchAllUsers = () => {
       fetch(`${url}/${page}/15`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                dispatch(setAllUsers(data.list));
            })
            .catch(err => console.log('Error message: ', err))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchAllUsers();
    }, [page])

    const handleScroll = () => {
        dispatch(setPage());
    }

    window.onscroll = function () {
        if(window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop === document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
            handleScroll();
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className="allUsersList">
            {
                allUsers ? (
                    allUsers.map((user, index) => (
                        <Link key={user.id} to={`/user/${user.id}`}>
                            <User name={user.name} lastName={user.lastName} prefix={user.prefix} title={user.title} img={user.imageUrl}/>
                        </Link>
                    ))
                ) : (
                    <div> Loading... </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default AllUsersList;
```

Here is UserDetails component:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setSelectedUser, removeUser, setSelectedUsersHistory } from '../redux/actions/actions';

export const UserDetails = () => {
    const selectedUser = useSelector(state => state.setSelectedUserReducer);
    const selectedUsersHistory = useSelector(state => state.setSelectedUsersHistoryReducer);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const {userId} = useParams();
    const fetchUserDetails = () => {
        fetch(`${url}/${userId}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                 dispatch(setSelectedUser(data));
              }
            )
            .catch(err => console.log('Error message: ', err))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(userId && userId!=='') fetchUserDetails();
        
        return () => {
            dispatch(removeUser())
        }
    }, [userId])


    return (
        <div className="userDetails">
            {
                Object.keys(selectedUser).length === 0 ? (
                    <div>Loading...</div>
                ) : (
                    <div>{selectedUser.name}</div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserDetails;
```

And here is the App,js with routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import AllUsersList from './components/AllUsersList';
import UserDetails from './components/UserDetails';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={AllUsersList} />
          <Route path="/user/:userId" exact component={UserDetails} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Seems to me if you've already fetched `allUsers` then you don't want to fetch again... but `allUsers` seems dependent on this `page` value also selected from redux state. I guess you should also cache the page value the current `allUsers` array is related to and only refetch when the page value is actually different than before.

Comment: That’s what I think I already did but clearly I am wrong but do not know where exactly. In useEffect I passed dependency [page] so logically it should fetch only in case if page changes, but yeah still I am wrong at some part and I can’t find on which part exactly.

Comment: When you navigate from "/" to a specific page, I believe `AllUsersList` is unmounted, and when you navigate back to "/" I believe is it remounted.

Comment: When I am navigating from “/“ to different component, I think data is already re-fetched, because  actually all of the users have image source link which is one same link and generating pictures automatically so when I am going from “/“ to different component image is changing which would happen in the only case if data was already fetched after navigating from “/“

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit difficult to follow. Yes, the data is fetched when on "/", so when going to a different component it is already fetched. Isn't the issue now that navigating *back* to "/" is triggering another data fetch (*of the same data*)? Isn't this the issue you are asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try useMemo()? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

It "memoizes" your page once it's been rendered.  It is not a guarantee for every render, but it does generally work in my experience.

Comment: Michael, do you mean to do use useMemo() for the whole component?

Comment: It actually might be better to put your function calls that change state inside a useEffect() block before returning your JSX in your components.  Which it looks like you did.  So to prevent re-fetching, I use graphQL and set the fetch-policy to re-use the cache.  https://medium.com/@galen.corey/understanding-apollo-fetch-policies-705b5ad71980.  Not sure how to take advantage of the cache outside of graphQL, I'm afraid.

Comment: okay will dig in more, thank you so much for your attention and helping!